# O SO.ru e o SO.es têm muito menos downvotes do que o SO, mas no SO.pt é muito mais. O que poderia explicar isso?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, voto-contra

É engraçado, eu me inscrevi para responder a perguntas sobre python recentemente, e a grande maioria foi rejeitada. Reconheço que algumas delas são de má qualidade, mas tão ruins assim?

Portanto, tentei comparar a taxa de perguntas com votos negativos na página inicial dos vários sites semelhantes da rede stacokverflow quinta-feira, 29, por volta das 11h da manha.

| SO | SO.es | SO.ru | SO.pt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8,3% | 0% | 14.58% | 70% |

Para reproduzir, aqui estã meu código

```
// Selecione os elementos que contêm os itens de número (use um seletor CSS apropriado)
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.s-post-summary--stats-item-number');
var total = document.querySelectorAll(".s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized");

// Comptez le nombre d'éléments négatifs
var negativeCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var number = parseInt(elements[i].textContent);
  if (number < 0) {
    negativeCount++;
  }
}

// Calcule a porcentagem
var totalCount = total.length;
console.log(total.length);
console.log(negativeCount);
var percentage = (negativeCount / totalCount) * 100;

// Mostra
console.log('Porcentagem de perguntas negativas : ' + percentage + '%');
```

Então, analisei o número de publicações negativas ([você pode executar novamente meu comando aqui](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352467/total-number-of-downvoted-posts)) em cada comunidade (esqueci do Japão, mea culpa):

| site | SO | SO.es | SO.ru | SO.pt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nbdownvoted | 8998447 | 30520 | 122237 | 87896 |
| nbposts | 23758113 | 192759 | 453134 | 154187 |
| % | 37% | 15% | 26% | 57% |

A proporção de publicações negativas parece ser significativamente maior na comunidade portuguesa do que nas outras. Perguntei-me então se isso era significativo fazendo [um teste Z](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_Z) entre a SO e as outras. O teste Z indica se as diferenças entre as proporções observadas são estatisticamente significativas.

| site | SO/SO | SO/SO.es | SO/SO.ru | SO/SO.pt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z | 0 | 198.8814 | 149.99 | 154.2655 |
| p | .5 | < .00001 | < .00001 | < .00001 |

Portanto, podemos concluir que as proporções de publicações negativas variam significativamente entre o SO e cada um dos outros sites (SO.es, SO.ru e SO.pt). As diferenças observadas são estatisticamente siganificativas e não podem ser atribuídas ao acaso. Os falantes de russo e espanhol *downvotaram* significativamente menos do que a comunidade de língua inglesa, mas os falantes de português *downvotaram* significativamente mais do que a comunidade de língua inglesa. Como esse fenomeno pode ser explicado?

Comment: Os dados que apresentou na pergunta estão fora de contexto, não levaram em consideração os fatores variáveis sobre cada um dos sites, como: são comunidades diferentes, situações diferentes, épocas diferentes, tempo de vida diferentes. Se quer entender o que são downvotes (e evita-los), você (ou qualquer participante do site deve buscar ler o que [***já foi debatido***](/search?q=votos+negativos), de resto a **[meta-tag:faq] explica o porque as perguntas mal elaboradas são negativadas**. Caso queiram debater, podem fazer isso no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146944/).